# API gateway SQS integration with SendMessageBatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs

I am creating an API gateway-SQS integration.
My APIs are bulk update in nature. Hence in a single API call, I will get list of inputs.
Is it possible to send each of input as a separate SQS message?
I checked: [SendMessageBatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessageBatch.html) documentation. According to it, I need to know how many messages I need to send, which is not possible in my case.
Also SendMessageBatch as limit of 10 messages per batch.

Ideally, I want something like this: API gateway receives bulk update call, for each input in that API request, it will send a message to SQS.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear how you can use API gateway with lambda in your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally, I want something like this: API gateway receives bulk update call, for each input in that API request, it will send a message to SQS.

You will need to use a **lambda function** to do this:

```
API Gateway ---> Lambda function ---> SQS
```

In this case, lambda will get the bulk of your records, and then send them one-by-one to same or different SQS queues.

Comment: Hi,Yes Lambda is one way to achieve this. But I don't want to add additional hop in my API processing. So looking for some way to achieve this using only API gateway [maybe something with requestTemplates ?]

Comment: @shubhamtambere How did it go? Did you find any alternative way?